# ngStorage not store the data if placed before $state.go

Tags: angularjs, ng-storage

Partials of my code below,

page1 controller 1

```
$scope.function1 =function() {
  $localStorage.hello ='test abc';
  $state.go('page2');
};
```

page2 controller 2

```
$scope.init =function() {
  if($localStorage.hasOwnProperty('hello')) {
    $scope.token =$localStorage.hello;
  }else {
    $scope.token =$localStorage.hello;
    $state.go('page1');}
};
```

when running the code, after call function1, it will auto redirect to page2, and page 2 will init the init function, but strange thing is that $localStorage.hello not exist now, so it return no thing,but after refresh the page2, data come out, any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this one?

Comment: Have you checked that `$localStorage` exists in the scope of your controller?